# Buefy pagination change event issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, buefy

I'm new to vue currently trying to use the buefy library to use pagination to fetch a limited number of rows at once to improve page load performance. This is most of my code.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <b-table
      :data="filter_list"
      :paginated="isPaginated"
      :row-key="(f) => f.id"
      :per-page="25"
      :current-page="currentPage"
      :pagination-simple="isPaginationSimple"
      :pagination-position="paginationPosition"
      :default-sort-direction="defaultSortDirection"
      :sort-icon="sortIcon"
      :sort-icon-size="sortIconSize"
      default-sort="version"
      aria-next-label="Next page"
      aria-previous-label="Previous page"
      aria-page-label="Page"
      aria-current-label="Current page"
      @change="getRows"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import data from "./data";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      filter_list: data,
      isPaginated: true,
      isPaginationSimple: true,
      paginationPosition: "bottom",
      defaultSortDirection: "desc",
      sortIcon: "arrows-v",
      sortIconSize: "is-small",
      currentPage: 1,
      perPage: 10,
      totalPages: 0,
    };
  },
  components: {},
  computed: {},
  methods: {
    getRows(currentPage) {
      console.log(currentPage.currentPage);
      // call rest api here with the current page number and push the response
      // into filter_list

    },
  },
  mounted() {},
};
</script>
```

Here is the live code sandbox  https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-lichterman-6n4ep?file=/src/App.vue:0-1254.

I want to fire the `getRows` method and subsequently a rest API request in it to fetch all the rows for a particular page. The API being requested has the logic for page number and total number of pages built in. It takes the page number as a parameter and returns 25 rows (also a parameter) of data.

I don't see the `getRows` method being fired when I click on the next/previous page arrow and mainly need help with this. I've mostly referred to https://buefy.org/documentation/pagination/ and I'm not so sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

buetify table has no `change` event, but `page-change`:

```js
...
@page-change="getRows"
...
getRows(currentPage) {
  console.log(currentPage);
},
```